# How to download a ggplotly plot with R Shiny downloadHandler?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm making a Shiny app in R. I use plotly to make my ggplots interactive, thus I have lots of ggplotly plots in the app. I would like to be able to download each one through a button on the interface.

My download button works for normal ggplot objects but not for ggplotly objects. A simple reproducible example would be:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(processx) # for orca()
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot1"), downloadButton('download1', 'Download Graph'))
  )

server <- function(input,output){
  make_plot1 <- function(){
    p1 = ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point()
    return(ggplotly(p1))}

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({ make_plot1() }) 

  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {'plot1.png'},
    content = function(file) {
      # try 1
      png(file)
      print(make_plot1())

      # try 2
      #plotly_IMAGE(make_plot1(), format = "png", out_file = file)

      # try 3
      #orca(make_plot1(), file)

      #try 4
      #export(make_plot1(), file = file)

      dev.off()
      })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Some things I've tried are commented out in that code.

Try 1 is based on [how I would normally handle plot objects in a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261269/downloadhander-save-plot-for-basic-plot-in-shiny)

Try 2 is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959635/exporting-png-files-from-plotly-in-r) and [this post](https://community.plot.ly/t/save-plotly-graphs-in-shiny/720)

Try 3 is based on [some plotly documentation](https://plot.ly/r/static-image-export/)

Try 4 is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998996/exporting-png-files-from-plotly-in-r-without-internet?lq=1)

All of these attempts either download a blank .png (try 1) or simply fail to download anything (tries 2-4). I suspect I'm not quite using the download Handler correctly. Anybody have suggestions for getting this working?

EDIT: For this case I want .png files, but there are some good answers on this thread for downloading interactive .html files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to accomplish this with a download button for some reason? If not, plotly has its own button in the modebar that downloads to a PNG.

[image]

Dashboard taken from https://plot.ly/r/dashboard/.

From the plotly support forum (https://community.plot.ly/t/remove-options-from-the-hover-toolbar/130/3), you can use `config()` to remove the other components.

```r
make_plot1 <- function() {
  p1 = ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point()
  p1 = ggplotly(p1) %>%
    config(
      modeBarButtonsToRemove = list(
        "zoom2d",
        "pan2d",
        "zoomIn2d",
        "zoomOut2d",
        "autoScale2d",
        "resetScale2d",
        "hoverClosestCartesian",
        "hoverCompareCartesian",
        "sendDataToCloud",
        "toggleHover",
        "resetViews",
        "toggleSpikelines",
        "resetViewMapbox"
      ),
      displaylogo = FALSE
    )
  return(p1)
}
```

You can also move the modebar so that it doesn't cover the plot, using CSS.

```css
.modebar {
    top: -30px !important;
}
```

Comment: Basically yes. I use `ggplotly(p1) %>% config(displayModeBar = F)` because I need to hide several things in the displayModeBar. Is there a way to remove everything except the 'Download plot as a png' from the displayBar?

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use htmlwidgets to save the file as an interactive html, in case that is preferable to a png.

To turn this html into a static graphic, a further workaround - if you for some reason do not want to use plotly's printing function at all - would be to save a png with webshot (which requires phantomjs). See code below.

```
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")
library("data.table")
library("plotly")
library("htmlwidgets")
library("webshot")


shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(

    mainPanel(plotlyOutput("plot1"),
              downloadButton('download1', 'Download Graph'))
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {

    inputPlot1 <- reactive({
      p1 = ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_point()
      ggplotly(p1)
    })

    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
      print(inputPlot1())
    })

    output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {'plot1.html'},
      content = function(file) {

      htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(inputPlot1()), file)

        # Alternative using webshot with phantomjs
        # saveWidget(as_widget(inputPlot1()), "temp.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
        # webshot(url = "temp.html", file)

      }
    )

  }

) # closes shinyApp
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment to Wil's answer, you can remove the undesired buttons in the modebar as follows:

```
library(plotly)

x <- c(1:15)
y <- c(1:15)
xy <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
example <- ggplot(data = xy,aes(x = x,y = y)) + geom_line()

ggplotly(example) %>% 
  config(displaylogo = FALSE,
         collaborate = FALSE,
         modeBarButtonsToRemove = list(
           'sendDataToCloud',
           'autoScale2d',
           'resetScale2d',
           'hoverClosestCartesian',
           'hoverCompareCartesian',
           'zoom2d', 
           'pan2d',
           'select2d',
           'lasso2d',
           'zoomIn2d', 
           'zoomOut2d',
           'toggleSpikelines'
         )
  )
```

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39985051/1100107
- http://www.somesolvedproblems.com/2018/10/how-to-customize-plotlys-modebar.html
- `?plotly::config`

Comment: Hi. Would you happen to know what to do if I use the exact same thing for each of my 7 App graphs but it shows only the `Dowload as png` button on the first one, for the rest it also shows `toggleSpikelines` and `resetViewMapbox` for box and lasso select?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to download your ggplotly graphs with interactive feature, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734665/how-to-export-ggplotly-from-r-shiny-app-as-html-file/55738545#55738545).