# ggplotly toolbar position within shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

Using the code below, I could create my ggplotly graph. As shown in the image below, the ggplotly toolbar overlap with the plot's title. How can I move the toolbar to the left side of the plot?

Also, how can I add a space between the title and the graph? I tried to do so by adding "br()" but it did not work?

I was wondering if there any way to remove "County" in the box so it only shows the name of the county (i.e., "Allen County" appears in the box instead of "County: Allen County").

[image]

```
      linedataPlot_60 <- reactive ({


     line_60 <- ggplot(linedata_60(),
           aes(
             x = Year,
             y = Percentage,
            # colour = interaction (County.y, Age_Group),
             colour = County

           )) + geom_line(size = 1)+ #ylim(0,30)+
      geom_point(size = 1.5,
                 shape = 21,
                 fill = "white" ) +   #scale_colour_manual(values=cbbPalette) +
      theme_bw() + #scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,40,1)) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank(),legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"), plot.title = element_text(
        hjust = 0.5,
        size = 9,
        colour = "Black",
        face = "bold"
      ),axis.text=(blue.bold.10.text), axis.title=blue.bold.10.text)+
      ggtitle(paste(
        input$sex_,
        "Older Population (60 or over) in the Selected Counties",

      "\n",
        "(2010 to 2050)"
      ))
       ggplotly(line_60) 

  })

  output$line_60 <- renderPlotly ({
    linedataPlot_60()
  })
```

Comment: Any ideas? Comments?

Answer (score 1):

For tooltip, please modify `aes` as `ggplot(linedata_60(),aes(x = Year,y = Percentage,colour = County,text=paste(County)))`. Then call `ggplotly` as `ggplotly(line_60,tooltip=c("x","y","text"))`. To avoid overlapping of title, please update `ggtitle` as `ggtitle(paste("\n",input$sex_,"Older Population (60 or over) in the Selected Counties","\n(2010 to 2050)"))`.

To move or remove modebar components, please look at this [How to download a ggplotly plot with R Shiny downloadHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171951/how-to-download-a-ggplotly-plot-with-r-shiny-downloadhandler)