# Rshiny - Plotly Add watermark logo to plot only if download initiated

Tags: r, shiny, download, plotly, watermark

I am building a shiny app and in this app I have a plot and I decided to use renderPlotly and ggplotly to render it.

Using [this](https://plotly.com/r/logos/) link, it is fairly easy to create a watermark to a ggplotly plot.

However, I want this watermark to be generated only on the downloaded png version of my plot and not on the one rendered that users see while using the app.

Is this possible ? I thought about disabling he download button and using the download handler to generate a new plot with a watermark, but it seems very complicated and not at all efficient looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171951/how-to-download-a-ggplotly-plot-with-r-shiny-downloadhandler) question

Any help ?

Comment: I once had a similar idea, but I gave up on it, since I realized that quite a number of dashboard users don’t use the download button, but just take a screenshot with a clipping tool. So the best option was to display the watermark in the actual plot.